# C# Microsoft Bot Schema Teams Image cropping off the top and bottom

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I had a question regarding Teams Microsoft Bot framework. Whenever my bot sends an adaptive card, the top and the bottom of the photo continue to cut off. Inside the adaptive card is the hero card image, it seems I'm unable to resize it to make it fit. I've tried making the image smaller and larger to see if that would fix the issue. Below is a screenshot of the issue I am having.

I'm hoping someone has run into the same issue and if this is fixable or not. Thank you.

Image being used; https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfnEw.jpg

```
   public async Task<SendResult> SendAsync(NotificationTeamsAttempt attempt)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attempt.ConversationId))
                throw new Exception("Conversation Id is required.");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attempt.ServiceUrl))
                throw new Exception("Service Url is required.");

            using (var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(attempt.ServiceUrl), _clientId, _clientSecret))
            {
                var activity = MessageFactory.Text("");
                activity.Attachments.Add(attempt.Attachment());
                activity.Summary = attempt.Summary();
                var response = await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(attempt.ConversationId, activity);
                return new SendResult
                {
                    IsSuccess = true,
                    DispatchId = response.Id
                };
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return new SendResult
            {
                IsSuccess = false,
                Exception = exception
            };
        }
    }


   public override Attachment Attachment()
    {
        var card = new ThumbnailCard
        {
            Title = "Post submitted for review by " + DraftAuthor,
            Subtitle = DraftTitle,
            Text = DraftDescription,
            Images = new List<CardImage>(),
            Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
        };
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TeamsUrl))
        {
            card.Buttons.Add(new CardAction
            {
                Type = "openUrl",
                Title = "Review in Teams",
                Value = TeamsUrl.Replace("null", $"%22post%7C{DraftId}%7C{DraftId}%22")
            });
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SPUrl))
        {
            card.Buttons.Add(new CardAction
            {
                Type = "openUrl",
                Title = "Review in SharePoint",
                Value = $"{SPUrl}?postId={DraftId}&sourceId={DraftId}"
            });
        }
        return card.ToAttachment();
    }
```

Please disregard the black lines I've added. But below you can see where the image is cropping off.
[Image of the cropping.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LBGi.png)

Comment: Could you please share the adaptive cards JSON?

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I'm just using the out-of-the-box C# default adaptive card. I am more than happy to post my C# snippets if that helps any.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could point us to the sample if any, that you are using. So that we can repro the issue with same image.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT thanks again for the reply, I've gone ahead and added a few code snippets. I'm hoping this helps, if you require more let me know. This is also the image being used; https://imgur.com/a/hkcSkrJ

Comment: We tried this using Adaptive card and Thumbnail card. I could see image was rendering fine in both the cases.  
Thumbnail Card : https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOBZR.png  
Adaptive card : https://i.stack.imgur.com/cllof.png

Comment: Could you please help us with the repro of this issue?

Comment: Could you please confirm if you are still facing this issue? If yes, then Could you please help us with the repro of this issue?

Comment: Hi, apologies. Yes, I am still facing the same issue, I apologize it's been super hectic. Is there any other information I could provide you with besides what is in the above post? @Meghana-MSFT

Comment: Could you please try the [size property](https://www.adaptivecards.io/explorer/Image.html) in adaptive card and check if that helps.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft I will give it a try now and get back to you!

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft I was still unable to get this to work properly, there is no size to change as well.

Comment: We are using the below JSON and we get the perfect image without cropping --   {
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "size": "Medium",
      "weight": "Bolder",
      "text": "card image test"
    },
    {
      "type": "Container",
      "items": [
        {
          "title": "Public test 1",
          "type": "Image",
          "url": "https://i.imgur.com/OiJNN03.jpeg"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.0"
}

Answer (score 0):

Moving comment to answer -

We are using the below JSON and we get the perfect image without cropping -- `{ "type": "AdaptiveCard", "body": [ { "type": "TextBlock", "size": "Medium", "weight": "Bolder", "text": "card image test" }, { "type": "Container", "items": [ { "title": "Public test 1", "type": "Image", "url": "https://i.imgur.com/OiJNN03.jpeg" } ] } ], "$schema": "adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json", "version": "1.0" }`